# html5 number field distinguish event if value increase or decrease

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using HTML5 number field to set top Position , when number field is increased with up [inside number field] i need to increase the top value vice versa if it is decrease then need to decrease top value.

```
$("#font_y_pos").change(function(event) {
var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();

if (!obj)
    return;

var y_pos = obj.getTop() - $(this).val();
obj.set('top', y_pos);
canvas.renderAll();
               });
```

but how can i distinguisg this 2 event ??? if value is increased or decreased?

Answer (score 1):

```
// before the first click on the field, store the original value
elm.onfocus=function () {elm.prevValue = elm.value; };

elm.onclick= function () {
    // when clicking the field, write to log the diff between current value and previous
    console.log ((elm.prevValue - elm.value)>0); // output=true/false depending on your direction
    // store current value as previous for next iteration
    elm.prevValue = elm.value;
};
```